# using a mail template in an action

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

Using the Symfony 1.4 framework, is it possible to take a template from the lib/mail directory and use it as a template within an action? I don't think using setTemplate will be possible for this, as this is the native method:

```
   public function setTemplate($name, $module = null)
    {
      if (sfConfig::get('sf_logging_enabled'))
      {   
        $this->dispatcher->notify(new sfEvent($this, 'application.log', array(sprintf('Change template to "%s/%s"', null === $module ? 'CURRENT' : $module, $name))));
      }   

      if (null !== $module)
      {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        $name = sfConfig::get('sf_app_dir').'/modules/'.$module.'/templates/'.$name;
      }   

      sfConfig::set('symfony.view.'.$this->getModuleName().'_'.$this->getActionName().'_template', $name);
    }
```

Comment: Could you post revelant code and not the one from `setTemplate`? And also explain better what do you want: where are your template? What is in lib/mail? which action are you talking about? etc ..

Comment: The templates are living in lib/mail, so an example could be lib/mail/confirmation_email.php. In an action, I want to use the template lib/mail/confirmation_email.php instead of apps/app_name/modules/module_name/template.php

Comment: Why templates are in this folder?

Comment: Because he wants to use the templates cross-application

Comment: Then he should use a plugin for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the templates in more projects you could make a plugin for that, or just [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) the module/template folder.

If you use the symlink, you can still use the `setTemplate()` function and all template will always be the same on every project.

Or you could rewrite the `setTemplate()` function, to accept a third argument and read the file from the `sf_lib_dir` instead of the `sf_app_dir`